# Integral homology groups of the complexe projective n-plane

Tags: homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

I am reading "Morse theory" by Milnor and on page 27 we have proved that the homotopy type of CP^n is of a CW-complex of the form : a 0-cell attached to a 2-cell attached to a 4-cell ... attached to a 2n-cell.µ
Then Milnor says it follows that the integral homology groups of CP^n are given by
H-i(CP^n;Z) = Z for i = 0,2,4,...,2n and
H-i(CP^n;Z) = 0 for other values of i.

So here is my question : what is the link between homotopy type and homology in my precis case ?

Thanks !

Comment: Check any textbook in algebraic topology.

Comment: What do you want to know exactly? I don't understand your question...

Comment: You want to check out "cellular homology."